# Hasura connect error when i filter like with accentuation on flutter

Tags: flutter, hasura

When i put a filter with accentuation in connect.subscription(getAllQuery) just doesn't respond and keeps trying and trying to loop

```
subscription getAllProduto {
produto(where: {descricao: {_ilike: "%feijão%"}}, order_by: {descricao: asc}) {
id
descricao
}
}
```

And when i put only _ilike: "%feij%" it´s work perfectly. Do you know what´s de problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of graphql_flutter you are using? Your result.hasException is null? Can you put all the Query Widget code here?

Comment: I'm not using graphql_flutter, I'm using hasura_connect. Anyway I don't need a subscription at this point and I will switch to a query that works well. And there is no exception because hasura_connect goes into a loop and keeps trying to make the query again until it crashes. The problem is certainly the hasura connect. I will do a test with graphql_flutter too.